# Setup/Start running Selenium tests between two systems

Tags: php, testing, selenium

I develop code on my main OS (Windows 7) and execute it on my VM (Ubuntu Server 12.04.4). VM is running on VMware Workstation. Selenium server (jar file) I was starting on main OS, but I'm not sure wether I should pass anything in parameters to it, so that it would know where to listen for tests.

I understand, that those should be the following steps

1. Start Selenium Server on main OS
2. Execute test on Ubuntu server
3. Make somehow it work
4. Enjoy the result

Any help with setting this infrasture would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can start selenium tests on another machine, which does not have the server running

Comment: I did it long time ago, but I just can't remember the setup.

Comment: Maybe you can compile your tests with the selenium jars in the include path, so they can be perfectly executable if JVM is ran on the ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

1. Start Selenium [Grid Hub](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#starting-a-hub) on main OS:

   `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar -role hub`
2. Start [Selenium node](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#starting-a-node) on Ubuntu:

   `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar -role node  -hub http://main-os-address:4444/grid/register`
3. Specify host in test cases (address of Selenium Hub):

   `setHost("127.0.0.1")`
4. Run test case from command line on main OS. It will start testing on Ubuntu VM.
5. Enjoy the result

Comment: Will definitely try it out.